# Using OR operator with Lookahead and length limitter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex in which I want to test for 2 things. The string is only valid when it starts with `+20` and its length is between 1 and 5, or when it doesn't start with +20 but it still has the plus sign `+` as its first character (example `+50`) and its length is between 1 and 7 then it's valid too.
Here is what I wrote for this validation :

`/^\+(?=20){1,5}|^\+(?!20){1,7}/g`

I tested it but it doesn't work how I intended for it and I dont understand why.

Comment: The 2nd group `+(?!20)` isn't explicit enough `+50` should match but so should `+Xx`. If 5 characters are max what can the last two be? Numbers, Words?...?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain what's wrong with your regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is close, but you need to:

- add the character selectors `.` to be quantified (`.` can work to match everything)
- constrain the end of the string to prevent the length from going over the max with `$`
- can remove `g` flag since you only want one match

---

That leaves you with:

```js
/^\+(?=20).{1,5}$|^\+(?!20).{1,7}$/
```

which you can also write as

```js
/^\+((?=20).{1,5}|(?!20).{1,7})$/
```

Answer (score 2):

In your regular expression, `(?=20){1,5}` reads, "execute the positive lookahead `(?=20){1,5}` between 1 and 5 times". That has the same effect as executing it once, clearly not what you want. What you want for that part of the expression is

```
(?=20).{1,5}
```

which reads, "match between 1 and 5 characters, the first two of which must be '20'".

That's still a problem however, because that matches '+20012' in the string '+20012 quick brown dogs' You need an *end-of-string anchor*:

```
^\+(?=20).{1,4}$|...
```

Notice I also changed `{1,5}` to `{1,4}`, as the string may contain at most 5 characters, or at most 4 after '+'. Also observe that the above is the same as

```
^\+20.{1,2}$|...
```

which is simpler and arguably reads better. So you could modify your entire regular expression to be

```
^\+20.{1,2}$|^\+(?!20).{1,6}$/g
```

or, to reduce repetition,

```
^\+(?:20.{1,2}|(?!20).{1,6})$/g
```

For one, that matches '+200X'. It should, unless by,"...when it starts with +20..." you mean, "...when it starts with +20 not followed by a digit...". I have assumed you meant the latter in my solution that follows.

---

You could attempt to match the following regular expression:

```
^\+(?:20(\D.?)?|(?!20(?!\d)).{0,6})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bplaGg/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^           # match beginning of string
\+          # match '+'
(?:         # begin non-capture group
  20        # match '20'
  (?:\D.?)? # optionally match a non-digit that is optionally
            # followed by any character
|           # or
  (?!       # begin negative lookahead
    20      # match '20'
    (?!\d)  # negative lookahead asserts '20' is not followed by a digit
  )         # end negative lookahead
  .{0,6}    # match between 0 and 6 characters
)           # end non-capture group
$           # match end of string
```

Note that `'+200'` is matched by the second part of the alternation (the string does not begin with '20').